# How to set row height in Flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native

I tried to use getItemLayout but didn't success. And I can't find any other related parameters in the react native documentation.

Comment: Set `height` on the item you are rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `renderItem`to customize your item rows

```
renderItem={({item}) => <View style={{ height: 80 }}> // ... </View>}
```

for example.